# How to set equal right margin by geometry package?

Tags: geometry

It is weird that with the following options, geometry doesn't set the equal right margin, it will  be alternating on even and odd pages:

```
\newgeometry{hmargin={.5in,1.5in},vmargin={0in,0in}}
```

[image: non-equal right margin]
I want to have all the page have right margin 1.5in and left margin 0.5in, how to do this?
MME:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{hmargin={.5in,1.5in},vmargin={0in,0in}}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\newpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the [`amsart`](//ctan.org/pkg/amscls) issues the following

```
\ExecuteOptions{leqno,centertags,letterpaper,portrait,%
  10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final}
```

which sets the default options of the class. Note that this includes `twoside`, which necessarily implies a different left (typically even) and right (typically odd) page layout. [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) follows this requirement, switching the left/right margins according to the page number (odd or even).

If you want to maintain a consistent layout from one page to the next, issue `oneside` as part of the document class options:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, in fact I try to add `oneside` as an opition to `geometry` but not works. Thanks again!